# How many people or how much force is needed to pave a path through a forest?

Tags: natural-growth

[image]
This is the kind of path I mean. I'm assuming people don't actually take time to pave paths; rather so many people or so much force is applied onto the grass that it eventually just dies, leaving the path visible in the picture above.

**Based on some average calculations and assuming that the future pathway is currently inhabited by only small and short grasses (none exceeding the height of 6 inches), how many people of average weight and height need to step on the grass to create a path?**

Comment: I'm not sure this is a great fit for our scope; I don't see any clear worldbuilding component to this question, and it appears to be pretty solidly about the real world. Maybe it would be better fit on [outdoors.se]?

Comment: My cat used to carve a path across the grass, it's not about how many people or how much force, it's about repeat use. This question doesn't doesn't really belong here though.